# CSV Stock file- updating value in file

Tags: python, csv

This is the code im having problems with. It is a basic GTIN-8 checker with the addition of a quantity input, to then be deducted from a preset value in the CSV file, but writing to CSV's is a new concept, so I am struggling to get it functioning. I need it to deduct the input of quantity from the value in the CSV, then updating the value in the CSV if the quantity is too high. I would appreciate some insight.

The main problem is the wiping of the CSV and not appending to it, where as I need it to change the values in the file and update on command

```
import csv
new_rows = []
count = 1
while count==1:
    code=(input("Enter a GTIN-8 code or type done to exit"))
    length=len(code)
    if code == "done":
        f.close()
        exit()
    if length==8:
        int1=int(code[0])
        int2=int(code[1])
        int3=int(code[2])
        int4=int(code[3])
        int5=int(code[4])
        int6=int(code[5])
        int7=int(code[6])
        int8=int(code[7])
        codeDigit=int(int1*3+int2+int3*3+int4+int5*3+int6+int7*3)
        roundup=round(codeDigit, -1)
        Bcode8th=int(roundup-codeDigit)
        if Bcode8th==int8:
            quantity=(int(input("Enter a quantity")))
            if quantity <51:
                try:
                    val = int(quantity)
                except ValueError:
                    print("That's not an integer")
                    changes = {quantity}
                    with open('Stock.csv', 'rb') as f:
                        reader = csv.reader(f)
                    for row in reader:
                       row_one = row
                       for key, value in changes.items():
                           row_one = [ x.replace(key, value)for x in row_one 
                       new_rows.append(row_one) 
                with open('Stock.csv', 'ab') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f)
                    writer.writerows(new_rows)
            else:
                print("Try again")
    else:
        print("Try again")
```

Comment: What is the data? What isn't working? What is the error or undesired results? What is the desired results?

Comment: @Parfait        Data is the value in the file, which then needs to be updated by the user input. There is no error message but it just doesn't edit the value in the column of the CSV

Comment: In your try/except block, check indentation in `except`. Did you mean to read the csv file when user gets *ValueError*?

Comment: @Parfait       CSV needs to be read and written to only when there is a valid code and then quantity entered